# Help proving the ideal generated by $x_1, ...$ is not finitely generated on the ring of polynomial with infinite many variables.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, problem-solving

I have problems proving that the ideal $(x_1, x_2, \dots )$ on the ring of polynomials on infinitely many variables $R[x_1, x_2, \dots ]$ is not finitely generated as an ideal. I don't have any idea on how to proceed since the combinations that involve writing $x_i$ as a combination of a set of generators $f_1, \dots, f_m$ i.e. $x_i = g_1 f_1 + g_2 f_2 + \dots g_m f_m$, the $g_i$ can have any variable $x_k$. I thought that it may be helpful to notice that this is a maximal ideal; but I fail to connect this idea to the suppose set of generators $(f_1, \dots, f_m)$.

Comment: 1) This it's not a maximal ideal unless $R$ is a field. Is that an assumption you're making? (It doesn't actually matter, though.) 2) You seem to have a typo or two in your first sentence. 3) Hint: is it possible for $x_i$ to be in the span of $f_1,\cdots,f_m$ if $x_i$ doesn't appear in any $f_j$? Why?

Comment: I thought on that but since I am thinking on the span of $(f_1, \dots, f_m)$ as an ideal over $R[x_1, \dots ]$ it may happen that $x_k = g_1 \, f_1 + g_2 \, f_2 + \dots + g_m\, f_m$ and some $g_k$ has the variable $x_k$. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: If some $g_k$ has the variable $x_k$, what would need to happen to have $x_k$ equal to that sum? Hint: think about degrees.

Comment: Your right, if I have $x_k$ for a large enough $k$ then it must come from a combination of constant terms and degree one terms; but the supposed generators can't have $x_k$ as a linear term and they can't have constant terms since they are in $(x_1, \dots)$. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: let $f_1, \ldots, f_m$ be a finite subset of $R[x_1, x_2, \ldots]$. Then the set of $i$ such that $x_i$ appears in some $f_j$ is finite, and hence has a maximum element, $n$ say. $x_{n+1}$ belongs to the ideal $(x_1, x_2, \ldots)$, but how can it belong to the ideal $(f_1, \ldots, f_m)$?